# condition for differentiability of G at $t_0$

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

This question is Ex 2.13 from Le Gall's Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Processes book. Let $\varphi : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

For every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, set $$G(t) = \int_{0}^{1} \lvert \varphi(x) - t \rvert dx$$ Prove that $G$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. For a fixed $t_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ give a necessary and sufficient condition for $G$ to be differentiable at $t_0$.

The continuity part is easy, for the differentiability part I looked at $$\frac{G(t) - G(t_0)}{t} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\lvert \varphi(x) - t \rvert - \lvert \varphi(x) - t_0 \rvert}{t} dx $$ I first tried to focus on $t > t_0$ and I split into $\{\varphi > t\}, \{t >= \varphi > t_0\}, \{t_0 > \varphi\}$. In this case to of the integrals simplify to $\lambda(\{\varphi > t\} \cap [0,1])$ and  $\lambda(\{t_0 \geq \varphi\} \cap [0,1])$, both of which exist in the limit $t \to t_0^{+}$. This leaves the middle term but it looked like $$\int_{[0,1] \cap \{\varphi \in [t_0, t)\}} \frac{t + t_0 - 2\varphi(x)}{t - t_0}dx$$ which I don't know how to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Note that whenever $x \in [0,1]$ is such that $\phi(x) \in [t_0,t)$ we have $$t+t_0-2\phi(x) \in (t+t_0-2t,t+t_0-2t_0] = (t_0-t,t-t_0]$$
and so $\left|\frac{t+t_0-2\phi(x)}{t-t_0}\right| \le 1$. Therefore $$\left|\int_{[0,1]\cap \{\phi \in [t_0,t)\}} \frac{t+t_0-2\phi(x)}{t-t_0}\mathrm{d}x\right| \le \int_{[0,1]\cap \{\phi \in [t_0,t)\}} 1\mathrm{d}x = \lambda([0,1]\cap\{\phi \in [t_0,t)\}) $$
with $\lambda$ denoting the Lebesgue measure. The RHS converges to $\lambda([0,1]\cap \{\phi = t_0\})$ as $t \to t_0^+$, so if $\phi \ne t_0$ almost-everywhere on $[0,1]$ we have existence of the limit. Computing the limit $t\to t_0^-$ in the same way will show they agree and so we have existence of the limit as $t\to t_0$.

If instead $\lambda([0,1]\cap \{\phi = t_0\}) \ne 0$ then note $$\begin{align*}
\frac{G(t)-G(t_0)}{t-t_0} &= \int_{[0,1]\cap \{\phi = t_0\}} \frac{|\phi(x)-t|-|\phi(x)-t_0|}{t-t_0} \mathrm{d}x+\int_{[0,1]\cap \{\phi \ne t_0\}} \frac{|\phi(x)-t|-|\phi(x)-t_0|}{t-t_0} \mathrm{d}x\\
&= \lambda([0,1]\cap \{\phi = t_0\}) \frac{|t_0-t|}{t-t_0} +\int_{[0,1]\cap \{\phi \ne t_0\}} \frac{|\phi(x)-t|-|\phi(x)-t_0|}{t-t_0} \mathrm{d}x\end{align*}.$$
The final integral will converge as $t\to t_0$ in the same way we showed above (since clearly $\phi \ne t_0$ almost-everywhere on $[0,1]\cap \{\phi\ne t_0\}$). However $\lambda([0,1]\cap \{\phi = t_0\}) \frac{|t_0-t|}{t-t_0}$ will not converge as $t \to t_0$ as it has different left/right limits. So our necessary and sufficient condition is that  $\lambda([0,1]\cap \{\phi = t_0\}) = 0$.